# Perform a destructive video trim in OSX Photos

Tags: macos, mojave, photos.app

I would like to trim my videos in Photos app running on macOS Mojave, and consequently, reclaim valuable hard disk space.

- Photos only appears to do a non-destructive trim, so it doesn't for up hard disk space.
- When I edit with an external application such as quicktime, I am unable to save over the original video once my edits are complete.
- I could export, and reimport the video into photos, however I would loose the metadata such as date, time, camera settings, and location.

Is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: what kind of trim are you talking about ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to reduce the file size of a Video is to change its resolution (quality).

For that you will use the Export command.

Once exported to a lower resolution, the process is not reversible.

[image]

Standard definition (480p) is good for standard-definition TV.

If the video will play on a high-definition TV or display, choose one of the high-definition formats: 720p or 1080p.

4K is used for ultra-high-definition TVs and displays.

720 is most common and a good balance between good picture at reasonable file size.